# Best picture Oscar winner with least number of total Oscar wins

Tags: academy-awards

Among films that won an Oscar for Best Picture, which one has the fewest Oscars won in all the categories?

Is there a film that won only Best Picture and didn't win in any other categories?

Comment: probably because it shows no research.

Answer (score 24):

Here is a list of all the Best Picture winners, listing for each of them the number of:

- **wins**: the number of Academy Awards that it won (e.g. *Titanic* won 11), and
- **misses**: the number of Academy Awards that it was nominated for but didn't win (e.g. *Titanic* was nominated for 14 awards and won 11, so it had 3 misses).

(To get the total number of nominations (including those won), just add the number of wins and misses.) These are presented in increasing order of awards won, breaking ties by increasing order of nominations (either “misses” or total; for a given number of wins the order is naturally the same).

This does not count the Technical Achievement Award for [*Gone With the Wind*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031381/awards), or the Honorary Awards for [*Gone With the Wind*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031381/awards), [*The Best Years of Our Lives*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0036868/awards), and [*Oliver!*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063385/awards).

As you can see, there are three winners of Best Picture for which that was the only award they won, all the way up to the three well-known winners that won eleven awards in total.

- 1 (+0) [Grand Hotel (1932)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0022958/awards)
- 1 (+2) [The Broadway Melody (1929)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0019729/awards)
- 1 (+7) [Mutiny on the Bounty (1935)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0026752/awards)
- 2 (+0) [Wings (1927)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0018578/awards)
- 2 (+2) [All Quiet on the Western Front (1930)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0020629/awards)
- 2 (+3) [The Greatest Show on Earth (1952)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0044672/awards)
- 2 (+4) [Spotlight (2015)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1895587/awards)
- 2 (+5) [You Can't Take It with You (1938)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0030993/awards)
- 2 (+9) [Rebecca (1940)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032976/awards)
- 3 (+1) [Sunrise: A Song of Two Humans (1927)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0018455/awards)
- 3 (+1) [Cavalcade (1933)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023876/awards)
- 3 (+3) [Crash (2004)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0375679/awards)
- 3 (+4) [Cimarron (1931)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0021746/awards)
- 3 (+4) [The Great Ziegfeld (1936)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0027698/awards)
- 3 (+4) [All the King's Men (1949)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0041113/awards)
- 3 (+4) [Midnight Cowboy (1969)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064665/awards)
- 3 (+4) [Argo (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1024648/awards)
- 3 (+5) [Casablanca (1942)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034583/awards)
- 3 (+5) [Gentleman's Agreement (1947)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0039416/awards)
- 3 (+5) [Moonlight (2016)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4975722/awards)
- 3 (+6) [12 Years a Slave (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2024544/awards)
- 3 (+7) [The Life of Emile Zola (1937)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0029146/awards)
- 3 (+7) [Rocky (1976)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075148/awards)
- 3 (+8) [The Godfather (1972)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/awards)
- 4 (+1) [Annie Hall (1977)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075686/awards)
- 4 (+1) [The Departed (2006)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407887/awards)
- 4 (+2) [Ordinary People (1980)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081283/awards)
- 4 (+3) [The Lost Weekend (1945)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0037884/awards)
- 4 (+3) [Hamlet (1948)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0040416/awards)
- 4 (+3) [Chariots of Fire (1981)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082158/awards)
- 4 (+3) [Million Dollar Baby (2004)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405159/awards)
- 4 (+4) [Marty (1955)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0048356/awards)
- 4 (+4) [Platoon (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091763/awards)
- 4 (+4) [Rain Man (1988)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095953/awards)
- 4 (+4) [A Beautiful Mind (2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268978/awards)
- 4 (+4) [No Country for Old Men (2007)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0477348/awards)
- 4 (+5) [Driving Miss Daisy (1989)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097239/awards)
- 4 (+5) [Unforgiven (1992)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105695/awards)
- 4 (+5) [Birdman or (The Unexpected Virtue of Ignorance) (2014)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2562232/awards)
- 4 (+6) [Tom Jones (1963)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057590/awards)
- 4 (+8) [The King's Speech (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1504320/awards)
- 5 (+0) [It Happened One Night (1934)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0025316/awards)
- 5 (+2) [In the Heat of the Night (1967)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061811/awards)
- 5 (+2) [The Silence of the Lambs (1991)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102926/awards)
- 5 (+3) [Around the World in 80 Days (1956)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0048960/awards)
- 5 (+3) [The French Connection (1971)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067116/awards)
- 5 (+3) [American Beauty (1999)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0169547/awards)
- 5 (+4) [One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073486/awards)
- 5 (+4) [The Deer Hunter (1978)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077416/awards)
- 5 (+4) [Kramer vs. Kramer (1979)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079417/awards)
- 5 (+5) [How Green Was My Valley (1941)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033729/awards)
- 5 (+5) [The Apartment (1960)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053604/awards)
- 5 (+5) [The Sound of Music (1965)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059742/awards)
- 5 (+5) [Braveheart (1995)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112573/awards)
- 5 (+5) [The Artist (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1655442/awards)
- 5 (+6) [Oliver! (1968)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063385/awards)
- 5 (+6) [Terms of Endearment (1983)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086425/awards)
- 5 (+7) [Gladiator (2000)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0172495/awards)
- 6 (+2) [An American in Paris (1951)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043278/awards)
- 6 (+2) [A Man for All Seasons (1966)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060665/awards)
- 6 (+3) [The Hurt Locker (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0887912/awards)
- 6 (+5) [The Godfather: Part II (1974)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071562/awards)
- 6 (+6) [Mrs. Miniver (1942)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0035093/awards)
- 6 (+7) [Forrest Gump (1994)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109830/awards)
- 6 (+7) [Chicago (2002)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0299658/awards)
- 6 (+8) [All About Eve (1950)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0042192/awards)
- 7 (+1) [The Best Years of Our Lives (1946)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0036868/awards)
- 7 (+1) [The Bridge on the River Kwai (1957)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050212/awards)
- 7 (+3) [Going My Way (1944)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0036872/awards)
- 7 (+3) [Lawrence of Arabia (1962)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056172/awards)
- 7 (+3) [Patton (1970)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066206/awards)
- 7 (+3) [The Sting (1973)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070735/awards)
- 7 (+4) [Out of Africa (1985)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089755/awards)
- 7 (+5) [Dances with Wolves (1990)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099348/awards)
- 7 (+5) [Schindler's List (1993)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108052/awards)
- 7 (+6) [Shakespeare in Love (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138097/awards)
- 8 (+2) [Slumdog Millionaire (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1010048/awards)
- 8 (+3) [Gandhi (1982)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083987/awards)
- 8 (+3) [Amadeus (1984)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086879/awards)
- 8 (+4) [On the Waterfront (1954)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047296/awards)
- 8 (+4) [My Fair Lady (1964)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058385/awards)
- 8 (+5) [Gone with the Wind (1939)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031381/awards)
- 8 (+5) [From Here to Eternity (1953)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045793/awards)
- 9 (+0) [Gigi (1958)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051658/awards)
- 9 (+0) [The Last Emperor (1987)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093389/awards)
- 9 (+3) [The English Patient (1996)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116209/awards)
- 10 (+1) [West Side Story (1961)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055614/awards)
- 11 (+0) [The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167260/awards)
- 11 (+1) [Ben-Hur (1959)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052618/awards)
- 11 (+3) [Titanic (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/awards)

Comment: I think the second number is supposed to be "nominated but not won"? It doesn't make sense to win oscars but not be nominated for any.

Comment: @Erik Yes, I explained that in two different ways in the first two sentences; can you suggest a way to make that clearer?

Comment: Ah, you're right. It reads a bit confusing. Maybe you could move the close parenthesis further right. -> (number of Oscar wins, number of Oscar nominations, not counting wins among nominations.) so the text stays together more?

Comment: Is *La La Land* missing from 2017? Not a big deal, since I'm sure it's not the answer to the question.

Comment: Ahah. `(11, 0)` for the director of [Braindead](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103873/). Life is full of surprises!

Comment: @ToddWilcox _La La Land_ didn't win best picture, _Moonlight_ did. Although, _La La Land_ was announced as the winner first before the correction.

Comment: @cfinley Oh right. And the years listed are the movie year, not the year the award was given.

Comment: @Erik Thanks for your comments. I made a series of edits to this answer to try to make that clearer, and I think I have finally arrived at the wording and notation that should make it clear. :-)